# Python textwrap Library - How to Preserve Line Breaks?

Tags: python, newline, word-wrap

When using Python's textwrap library, how can I turn this:

```
short line,

long line xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

into this:

```
short line,

long line xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

I tried:

```
w = textwrap.TextWrapper(width=90,break_long_words=False)
body = '\n'.join(w.wrap(body))
```

But I get:

```
short line, long line xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

(spacing not exact in my examples)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

try

```
w = textwrap.TextWrapper(width=90,break_long_words=False,replace_whitespace=False)
```

that seemed to fix the problem for me

I worked that out from what I read [here](http://docs.python.org/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.TextWrapper) (I've never used textwrap before)

Comment: Beware that in this case the wrapper considers \n as character and not as a line breaker, for instance it will assume that previously\npublished is one word. This causes formatting problems in many cases. So the solution with "\n".join(), given by user "far" is better.

Answer (score 24):

```
body = '\n'.join(['\n'.join(textwrap.wrap(line, 90,
                 break_long_words=False, replace_whitespace=False))
                 for line in body.splitlines() if line.strip() != ''])
```

Comment: Nearly 8 years later and still valid! Thank you!

Comment: Indeed! wrapping "lines" should be for "lines" not for the whole text ! thanks @far

Answer (score 6):

How about wrap only lines longer then 90 characters?

```
new_body = ""
lines = body.split("\n")

for line in lines:
    if len(line) > 90:
        w = textwrap.TextWrapper(width=90, break_long_words=False)
        line = '\n'.join(w.wrap(line))

    new_body += line + "\n"
```

Answer (score 6):

TextWrapper is not designed to handle text that already has newlines in it.

There are a two things you may want to do when your document already has newlines:

**1) Keep old newlines, and only wrap lines that are longer than the limit.**

You can subclass TextWrapper as follows:

```
class DocumentWrapper(textwrap.TextWrapper):

    def wrap(self, text):
        split_text = text.split('\n')
        lines = [line for para in split_text for line in textwrap.TextWrapper.wrap(self, para)]
        return lines
```

Then use it the same way as textwrap:

```
d = DocumentWrapper(width=90)
wrapped_str = d.fill(original_str)
```

Gives you:

```
short line,
long line xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

**2) Remove the old newlines and wrap everything.**

```
original_str.replace('\n', '')
wrapped_str = textwrap.fill(original_str, width=90)
```

Gives you

```
short line,  long line xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

(TextWrapper doesn't do either of these - it just ignores the existing newlines, which leads to a weirdly formatted result)

Answer (score 2):

Split, wrap+join, and rejoin:

```
def wrap(s):
    return "\n".join("\n".join(textwrap.wrap(x)) for x in s.splitlines())
```

Comment: Thanks! This works good in conjunction with argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter and argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it doesn't support that.  This code will extend it to do what I need though:

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/358228/

Answer (score 1):

```
lines = text.split("\n")
lists = (textwrap.TextWrapper(width=90,break_long_words=False).wrap(line) for line in lines)
body  = "\n".join("\n".join(list) for list in lists)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little module that can wrap text, break lines, handle extra indents (eg.a bulleted list), and replace characters/words with markdown!

```
class TextWrap_Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.Replace={'Sphagnum':'$Sphagnum$','Equisetum':'$Equisetum$','Carex':'$Carex$',
                      'Salix':'$Salix$','Eriophorum':'$Eriophorum$'}
    def Wrap(self,Text_to_fromat,Width):
        Text = []
        for line in Text_to_fromat.splitlines():
            if line[0]=='-':
                wrapped_line = textwrap.fill(line,Width,subsequent_indent='  ')
            if line[0]=='*':
                wrapped_line = textwrap.fill(line,Width,initial_indent='  ',subsequent_indent='    ')
            Text.append(wrapped_line)
        Text = '\n\n'.join(text for text in Text)

        for rep in self.Replace:
            Text = Text.replace(rep,self.Replace[rep])
        return(Text)


Par1 = "- Fish Island is a low center polygonal peatland on the transition"+\
" between the Mackenzie River Delta and the Tuktoyaktuk Coastal Plain.\n* It"+\
" is underlain by continuous permafrost, peat deposits exceede the annual"+\
" thaw depth.\n* Sphagnum dominates the polygon centers with a caonpy of Equisetum and sparse"+\
" Carex.  Dwarf Salix grows allong the polygon rims.  Eriophorum and carex fill collapsed ice wedges."
TW=TextWrap_Test()
print(TW.Wrap(Par1,Text_W))
```

Will output:

- Fish Island is a low center polygonal peatland on the
  transition between the Mackenzie River Delta and the
  Tuktoyaktuk Coastal Plain.

  - It is underlain by continuous permafrost, peat
    deposits exceede the annual thaw depth.
  - $Sphagnum$ dominates the polygon centers with a
    caonpy of $Equisetum$ and sparse $Carex$.  Dwarf $Salix$
    grows allong the polygon rims.  $Eriophorum$ and
    carex fill collapsed ice wedges.

Characters between the $$ would be in italics if you were working in matplotlib for instance, but the $$ won't count towards the line spacing since they are added after!

So if you did:

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize = (10,7))
ax.text(.05,.9,TW.Wrap(Par1,Text_W),fontsize = 18,verticalalignment='top')

ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
ax.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
```

You'd get:
[image]

Comment: thanks some part of you ans help me to solve my issue !

Answer (score 0):

I had to a similar problem formatting dynamically generated docstrings.  I wanted to preserve the newlines put in place by hand *and* split any lines over a certain length.  Reworking the answer by [@far](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2044053/far) a bit, this solution worked for me.  I only include it here for posterity:

```
import textwrap

wrapArgs = {'width': 90, 'break_long_words': True, 'replace_whitespace': False}
fold = lambda line, wrapArgs: textwrap.fill(line, **wrapArgs)
body = '\n'.join([fold(line, wrapArgs) for line in body.splitlines()])
```