# Python 3.4.3 - How to make textwrap work with itertools

Tags: python, python-3.4, python-itertools

I'm using this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import textwrap
import itertools

a = []

a.append('word1')
a.append('word2')
a.append('word3')
a.append('word4')
a.append('word5')
a.append('word6')
a.append('word7')
a.append('word8')
a.append('word9')
a.append('word10')

for permutation in itertools.permutations(a,):
    permutation = textwrap.TextWrapper(len=60,break_long_words=False,replace_whitespace=False)
    print(' '.join(permutation))
```

And get some information from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1166317/python-textwrap-library-how-to-preserve-line-breaks) and [here](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.TextWrapper.wrap), but can't solve my problem.

I just want to permute those words into all possible combinations non-repeatable phrase that have 60 characters length.

Comment: I’m not sure what you want to use the text wrapper there for. Also, you’re overwriting the permutation in the for loop.

Comment: I'm trying to only print phrases with 60 char len long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will print all permutations which, when combined into a single string, have the length 60:

```
for permutation in itertools.permutations(a):
    s = ' '.join(permutation)
    if len(s) == 60:
        print(s)
```

But it doesn’t make much sense to do this anyway, since permutations of a sequence will always contain all elements of that sequence, so the combined string will always have the same length, and only the order of the words inside change.

So you could just as well make the check first and only then loop over the permutations.

Or you could generate combinations which would allow for varying lengths.

Comment: Doesn't work properly. It just make me into a forever loop and don't print 60 char len =/

Comment: No, that cannot be an infinite loop. But it’s likely that you don’t find any result, especially with those example strings from your question (no combination will give you a string of length 60).

Comment: I'm trying this and don't work. '#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import textwrap
import itertools

a = 'just testing this to try and make this work'.split()

for permutation in itertools.permutations(a,):
    s = ' '.join(permutation)
    if len(s) == 60:
        print(s)'

Comment: actually, your script works perfectly, and all permutations will be 60 characters long (9 spaces, 5 letters/word * 9 words, 6 letters/word * 1 word). However, it takes python a while to print out all 3628800 permutations.

Comment: It doesn't work like I want. `#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import textwrap
import itertools

a=[]
a.append('test')
a.append('testttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt')
a.append('testing')
a.append('tested')
a.append('tester')

for permutation in itertools.permutations(a,):
    s = ' '.join(permutation)
    if len(s) == 60:
        print(s)` this formula just don't print anything.